# Stop SSDT being published when MSBuild publish run

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have a ClickOnce project that I'm publishing on DevOps.  I've set the `MSBuild Arguments` property for the WinForm solution's build stage in DevOps to `/target:Publish` in order to trigger the creation of all the ClickOnce files:

[image]

However, that solution also contains an SSDT project, and adding the `/target:Publish` setting appears to then cause the build process to try publish the SSDT too. That then fails with the error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(1808,5):
>   error MSB4044: The "SqlPublishTask" task was not given a value for the
>   required parameter "SqlPublishProfilePath"

Presumably it's failing because there's no publish profile specified in a build parameter for the SSDT to use.

I don't want MSBuild to publish the DacPac to a server, I just want it to create the DacPac. How can I stop the `/target:Publish` triggering the SSDT publish, is there another build argument I can add to stop that happening?

**Notes on what I tried so far to solve this, none of which has worked:**

- Read about the -target switch in the MS Build official docs [in the MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2017) and in the [MSBuild targets section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2017).
- Looked at the code in the .csproj file to try and identify the 'Publish' sections - think Publish must also call Build.
- Unticking Deploy for the SSDTs in the solution configuration in VS
- Adding entries for False in the Release and Deployment configurations in the SSDT's .csproj file, and also setting that to false for the Debug configuration ([as per this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9d1d54bc-171b-497b-9a77-53a6bf26ca36/whats-the-effect-to-deploytodatabase-in-sqlproj-file?forum=ssdt))
- Setting MSBuild to only publish one project using the MS Build arguments on DevOps ([as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891530/publish-one-web-project-from-solution-with-msbuild))
- Considered pulling the ClickOnce publish out into an entirely separate stage using Mage.exe as per this [Walkthrough: Manually deploy a ClickOnce application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-manually-deploying-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2017)
- Tried to create a publish profile that doesn't actually publish, so that the publish stage can complete ([was looking at this question for ideas on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032213/making-ssdt-just-generate-a-sql-script-and-not-deploy-a-database) and also the [official documentation for SqlPackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017))

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I solved the issue above a completely different way.  Instead of getting MSBuild to do what I wanted it to, I instead split the solution configuration in two, with one stage for the databases and one for the WinForms project without the databases.

I then used two separate VS Build stages on DevOps with only the WinForms stage still having `/target:Publish` set.

[I've written that up here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54851828/1879019), but would still like to know the answer to whether it's possible to tell MSBuild not to build the SSDTs when the target is set to Publish?